# Duplicate one layer into several open files (Photoshop CS5)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I know that I can duplicate one layer from a file into another one, but is it also possible to duplicate that one layer into more than one open file with one step or do I have to open the duplicate dialog for each time again?

Comment: See adobe's help file on creating actions for repetitive tasks in Photoshop: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7448a.html